# t-test: understanding alternative hypothesis, power, and noncentral distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, statistical-power, non-central

1. While the alternative hypothesis $H_a: \mu_c \ne \mu_t$ covers an *infinite* number of possible values for $\mu_t$, the power of the test can only be defined based on a *point* value of $\mu_t$ - is this statement true?
2. *If* the alternative hypothesis $H_a: \mu_c \ne \mu_t$ were true, then does the t-statistic follow the non-central t-distribution, with noncentrality parameter, $\lambda$? (e.g., [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution), [real-statistics](http://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/noncentral-t-distribution/))
3. Are all distributions under alternative hypotheses skewed/asymmetric? (e.g. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution), [real-statistics](http://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/noncentral-t-distribution/))

---

**My understanding of a t-test**

In general, I have heard that any test statistic can be summarised as (e.g., [statisticshowto](http://www.statisticshowto.com/standardized-test-statistic/), [duke.edu](http://sites.nicholas.duke.edu/statsreview/means/welch/)):

$$ \frac{x_\mathsf{obs} - x_\mathsf{hyp}}{S.E} \mathsf{\ \ \ (1)}$$

i.e., I interpret this as the 'standardised' difference (i.e., in units of standard error) between observed measurements and hypothesised values.

For the comparison of two sample means, Eq. 1 can be expressed more specifically to give the value of the t-statistic (e.g., [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test#Calculations), [real-statistics](http://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/two-sample-t-test-uequal-variances/)):

$$ t = \frac{\big(\bar{x_c} - \bar{x_t}\big) - \big(\mu_c - \mu_t\big)}{\sqrt{ \frac{s_c^2}{n_c} + \frac{s_t^2}{n_t} }} \mathsf{\ \ \ (2)}$$

where subscript $c$ and $t$ signify the control sample and test sample, respectively, and

- $\bar{x}$: mean of the observed sample
- $s$: the standard deviation of the observed sample
- $n$: the size of the observed sample
- $\mu$: the actual/assumed/hypothesised mean of the underlying population

In the case where the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu_c = \mu_t$, the second term in Eq. (2) becomes 0. *If* the null hypothesis were true, then the t-statistic follows the central t-distribution. The observed (sample-specific) value of $t$ (along with degrees of freedom, $\nu$) can then be used to find a $p$-value via:

$$ p = f(t,\nu) $$

where $f$ is some function (e.g., [T.DIST (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/t-dist-function-4329459f-ae91-48c2-bba8-1ead1c6c21b2) or [scipy.stats.ttest_ind (Python)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html)) and $\nu$ is approximated by the Welch-Satterthwaite equation:

$$ \frac{\Big( \frac{s_c^2}{n_c} + \frac{s_t^2}{n_t} \Big)^2}{ \frac{\Big(\frac{s_c^2}{n_c}\Big)^2}{n_c-1} + \frac{\Big(\frac{s_t^2}{n_t}\Big)^2}{n_t-1} } $$

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Only when the distributional assumptions are met. Non-normal data will have a non-central T limiting distribution. 3. Yes the general shape of a non-central T with non-zero NCP is skewed.

Comment: Interesting question! Welcome to CV. The "any test statistic can be summarized" sentence ignores omnibus test statistics (e.g., *F* tests), contingency-table test statistics (e.g., $\chi^{2}$ tests), test statistics formed using the [two one-sided tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/tost/info) form, and likely others.